# How to start spring scheduled task after a ThreadPoolTaskScheduler was destroyed?

Tags: spring-scheduled

I would like to start/end a scheduled task in Spring with a button clicked. The scheduled task annotated with @Scheduled is stopped like this:

```
@Autowired
private ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor;
@Autowired
private ThreadPoolTaskScheduler scheduler;

public void stop() {

    scheduler.destroy();
    executor.destroy();
}
```

but how to start this task again? The following tries does not work:

```
    scheduler.initialize();
    executor.initialize();
```

OR

```
    scheduler.getScheduledThreadPoolExecutor().prestartAllCoreThreads();
    executor.getThreadPoolExecutor().prestartAllCoreThreads();
```

How to do this? Any tips/suggestions are welcome.